# Extracting piston rod's "wire" C clips

Tags: piston, rod, clips

So now that I'm getting ready (soon :) ) to fit new pistons in my old Skoda Estelle engine, I found that the piston rods have "wire" C clips. I mean, they look like a piece of wire, no "eyes" or tabs with holes in which we normally put the pliers to squeeze the clip. Just like a C section of a spring. How can be those clips extracted? I guess using a needle-like screwdriver? I have seen this for instance, in power steering pumps, but much larger.

[image]

Comment: Can we get detailed pictures of what you're talking about?

Comment: yes, the clips looks like these: http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/images/g/73sAAOSweW5VDGfo/s-l225.jpg

Comment: If the clips have the angled end on them, use a screwdriver to pry them up, then get under them. It will take a small headed screwdriver to do this, please a lot of patience and some practice. Once the end is up a little bit from the groove, wiggle the screw driver up underneath of it, then work it out the rest of the way.

Comment: sorry another image, much more illustrative: http://product-images.qedmotorsport.co.uk/lotus/900-series/pistons-and-liners/Gudgeon-pin-circlip-standard-piston.jpg    so instead of the left one, I see the rods have the ones like show on the right

Comment: Thank you Paulster2, I haven't look in details to see if one of the ends are angled. Then, what if they aren't. At first glance I thought they were normal C clips, with tab ends, but broken so no more tabs. In fact, I did see that only one clip has only-but-one tab, meaning they broke the other end.

Answer (score 4):

Those gudgeon pin clips are the fiddly type! .. Get a sharp engineers angled scribe or similar, and try to lever one end of the C-clip away from the piston just enough the get a small narrow blade screwdriver under it, use the screwdriver approaching at the same angle as the gudgeon pin goes in.  Once you have the screwdriver sat under the clip use the engineers scribe and screwdriver together to work the C-clip out.. WATCH YOUR EYES TOO. sometimes those things come out with rather a lot of force.

Comment: "Watch your eyes" = **wear safety glasses!**  There's no point in *watching* your eyes get injured!  I believe @Orb knows this; that's why they said it.  I just want to clarify that this does *not* mean "squint".

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself some retaining ring pliers.  You can get them with fixed or interchangeable tips.  The interchangeable are cheaper but the fixed tip pliers are better in my opinion.  I feel they engage more solidly and predictably than the interchange tip models I've used.

Something with flat tips will work.
Like these:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I know these, but won't work with the C clips I have; they don't have any surface or tab for inserting an extractor tool. In fact, some of them are very deep into their groove I couldn't easily see them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the situation of your car or cars in general.

But pistons for my scooter come with G- or C-style clips, and have a grove through the bore of the bolt, as shown in the picture below. It's quite easy to grip the clips with needlenose pliers to remove or install them. This works even better if the teeth of the pliers are a little bigger than normal. Ah, and don't grip the clip from the opposed sides, just the wire on one side.

[image]

Comment: I see other pistons with C clips with a kind of groove or drill that seems to be for inserting a tool to then squeeze the clip, like in your pic, both only one side...I wonder if I could also drill my pistons, just enough to be able to push the rings out, without damaging or creating a possible fissure point.